# matrix and polynomial

Tags: matrices, polynomials, matrix-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be all the roots of $ x^3 + sx + t$. What is the determinant of the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & c\\
    b & c & a\\
    c & a & b
 \end{bmatrix}$?

I wrote the the system for $ p(a)=0,p(b)=0, p(c)=0$, tried to eliminate parameters $s,t$ and substitute into the expression for the determinant $3abc - a^3 - b^3 - c^3$, hoping to get zero, which didn't work. Also, I tried to show that singularity of the matrix of the system
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & a & a^3\\
    1 & b & b^3\\
    1 & c & c^3
 \end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
    q\\
    p\\
    1
 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0
 \end{bmatrix}$
implies that the determinant of the given matrix is zero, which also didn't work. What am I missing?

Should I use the symmetry of the matrix somehow?

Comment: Also look for the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials

Comment: Your method should work if you do the right thing - see my answer for what happens if you use $p(a)+p(b)+p(c)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^3+sa+t=b^3+sb+t=c^3+sc+t=0$ so that (adding the three expressions) $$(a^3+b^3+c^3)+s(a+b+c)+3t=0$$

Now equating coefficients in $x^3+sx+t=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ we get $a+b+c=0$ (coefficient of $x^2$) and $t=-abc$

Substituting these into the previous equation we get: $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=0$$

---

NOTE: suppose our equation had been $x^3+rx^2+sx+t=0$. We add the three expressions for $a,b,c$ as before to get:

$$(a^3+b^3+c^3)+r(a^2+b^2+c^2)+s(a+b+c)+3t=0$$

Equating coefficients as we did before $r=-(a+b+c), s=(ab+bc+ac), t=-abc$. If we then take the $r$ and $s$ terms to the other side, and substitute the $a,b,c$ expressions we get

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(ab+bc+ac)(a+b+c)=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$$

The two middle terms of the cubic each yield  factor $(a+b+c)$. This identity is particularly useful when $a+b+c=0$ (as is true here). In that case, the method I used above also works nicely.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder: how did you know that equating the coefficients will yield something useful?

Comment: @user130039 It is a standard technique in the analysis of polynomials - the coefficients of a monic polynomial turn out to be the elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots. In a polynomial of degree $n$ the constant term is $(-1)^n$ times the product of the roots and the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is -(sum of roots). You might want to explore Vieta's formulas.

Comment: Another thing you can do using these methods is to find the sum of powers of the roots - the first main equation in the note is a clue. If you multiply through the polynomial by $x^n$ before substituting and adding you get $(a^{n+3}+b^{n+3}+c^{n+3})+r(a^{n+2}+b^{n+2}+c^{n+2})+s(a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}+c^{n+1})+t(a^{n}+b^{n}+c^{n})=0$ which gives you a recurrence formula for the sums of powers (and links with the theory of recurrence relations generally).

Comment: And since $a+b+c=-r$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2−ab−bc−ac=(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ac)=r^2-3s$, the determinant has the value $r(3s-r^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\det(A) = 3abc - a^3 - b^3 - c^3 = -(a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca) = 0$ since $a + b + c = 0$ by Viete's theorem.